# How to convert varchar to decimal format? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, decimal, varchar

I am working with Pharmacy drug pricing data. The data resource I am using references drugs in the following format:

- NDC: 0002831517
- AWP: 001539667

AWP value has this format:

- Decimal, 4 digits before, 5 digits after

So I would be looking to see:

- AWP: 0015.39667

Whenever I use `CONVERT`, I get the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: My SQL Logic:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 NDC10,
                CONVERT(DECIMAL (9, 5), AWPUPRICE)
FROM   [TEST].[dbo].[NDC_CODES]
```

Comment: SELECT CAST(LEFT(@value,4) + '.' + RIGHT(@value, 5) AS DECIMAL(9,5))

Comment: "Whenever I use CONVERT..." - we need a *bit* more context than that. Maybe a *complete* code sample that demonstrates what you're trying to do.

Comment: Convert(bigint, AWP) * 0.00001?

Comment: This is my current sql: SELECT TOP 1000
NDC10,
CONVERT(DECIMAL (9, 5), AWPUPRICE)
  FROM [TEST].[dbo].[NDC_CODES]

Comment: Look at first comment...

Comment: Are the actual values like `NDC: 0002831517`? I don't see anything that even attempts to extract the numeric portion if so.

Comment: so basically the first 5 characters had nothing to do with the question ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what 5 characters you talking about? I referenced the NDC value to help give the question context to the AWP field (I.e. pricing). I am not sure I understand my question is not following guidelines. Please advise.

Comment: This question is valid and I've seen a lot of questions like this. why it is voted to close?!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 NDC10, CAST(LEFT(AWPUPRICE,4) + '.' + RIGHT(, 5) AS DECIMAL(9,5))
 FROM [TEST].[dbo].[NDC_CODES]
```